# Using Moment.js and Twix.js, can I list a range of dates at a monthly interval, but with each day equal to the day in the start date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm looking to use Moment.js and Twix.js to list a range of dates between two dates, at a monthly interval, but with each day equal to the day in the start date? Instead, the dates in the list all start at the first of each month. Below is my code.

```
var itr = moment.twix(new Date('2017-01-15'),new Date('2017-04-20')).iterate("months");
var range=[];
while(itr.hasNext()){
    range.push(itr.next().format("YYYY-MMM-DD"))
}
alert(range);
```

This results in 2017-Jan-01,2017-Feb-01 etc but what I want is 2017-Jan-15,2017-Feb-15, etc.

Is there a way to configure Twix or Moment to do what I want? I know I can probably find some pure JS to do this, but I'm writing a small plugin for a platform I use and Moment plus Twix gives me a lot of the flexibility and options I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible out of the box, probably for good reasons like not all months being equal, the occurrence of leap years and so on.

Let's take the example of start date being **2017-01-31** and end date being **2017-03-31**. There is no **2017-02-31** to be returned by the iterator, which makes the problem an ill-posed one. In case of a non-leap year, even **YYYY-01-29** may prove to be a problem.

That being said, with ill-posed problems we can make some compromises. Assuming you know upfront that you won't be running into situations like the one described above or that you accept some elements of the range to slip into the next month, we can modify the above code as follows:

```js
var startDate = moment('2017-01-15');
var firstDay = startDate.date();
var range=[];

var itr = startDate.twix('2017-04-20').iterate('months');
while(itr.hasNext()){
    range.push(itr.next().add(firstDay, 'days').format('YYYY-MMM-DD'));
}

console.log(range);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/twix.js/dist/twix.js"></script>
```

We basically record the day of the start date and add it to every moment object returned by the iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have explained that I would expect to deal with that sort of problem, e.g. by disallowing start dates past the 28th. This is great. Thanks again.